# Compressed in Python - Decompress in c#

Tags: c#, python, image, zlib, compression

I have a project where an image is saved to a sqlite3 database using Python.

I found this in the code:

```
im=buffer(zlib.compress(im.tostring()))
```

From a C# project i want to be able to see that image.

I tried a number of things, but I am still far from getting it right.

The corresponding Python code is:

```python
try:
    self.cur.execute("select img,mode,width,height from skitse where navn = ?",(label,))
except:
    im,w,h=self.ReturnNoSkitse()
else:
    data=self.cur.fetchone()
    if data is not None and len(data)>0:
        im=zlib.decompress(str(data[0]))
        mode=data[1]
        w=data[2]
        h=data[3]
        im=Image.fromstring(mode,(w,h),im)
        if mode!="RGB":
            im=im.convert("RGB")
        im=im.tostring()
```

In C#, I tried something like:

```cs
public static Image ToImage(string data)
{
    if (data == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, >false, false);
    return image; 
}
```

That just gives me nothing. Can anyone please hint me in the right direction?

Comment: Rumor has it, DotNetZip (which can be found amongst NuGet packages), has zlib compression/decompression support.

Comment: This isn't really related to images at all. Basically, you need to know what compression python zlib uses, and find its c# alternative. Shouldn't be too hard to google.

Comment: Ok I can see that. I still don't get the result I expect. I get the image shown twice.